# How can I use visual studio code features on android studio while coding in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to use some features that I can use with VS Code on Android Studio as well. Are these possible?
1- I want it to recognize the word written without distinguishing upper or lower case letters. For example, like the string example in the image below. Even if the letter s is written in lower case, vs code detects it, but android studio does not.
2- Refactor features are a lot through visual studio and it works. But I could not see these features in android studio. You can see it in the picture below.
3- Android studio warns on words other than English. How can we remove this problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can I am currently codding in flutter and also kotlin I installed `tabnine` plugin, tabnine is really usefull and save your time for example as u said when u type string, it automaticly show words that are related to that sitution and place where u code.

and for third problem u can ignore those words